# CentOS 7: Strange directories appearing in /

Tags: centos, handbrake

On my CentOS 7 (64 bit) machine some strange directories are appearing in the root directory /

I can't work out what's causing it, if I delete them they slowly start to reappear.

Here is a sample:

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 root  root  4096 Apr 19 09:15 Y-8f9479b39a92bac7-0000000000
drwxr-xr-x  2 root  root  4096 Apr 15 08:20 Y-af72e17029b2d6c1-0000000000
drwxr-xr-x  2 root  root  4096 Apr 20 09:30 YAg*-f8fe9fbc16e2d7e3-0000000000
drwxr-xr-x  2 root  root  4096 Apr 20 20:15 y:-cd1a6f4e05353e19-0000000000
drwxr-xr-x  2 root  root  4096 Apr 27 15:45 Y-df78a7ff0627a98c-0000000000
drwxr-xr-x  2 root  root  4096 Apr 22 14:50 Y-e340633e382d2dfa-0000000000
drwxr-xr-x  2 root  root  4096 Apr 22 11:10 Y-f63ddb0510f522bd-0000000000
drwxr-xr-x  2 root  root  4096 Apr 23 12:25 Yg=B-d85f91f40842530a-0000000000
drwxr-xr-x  2 root  root  4096 Apr 28 04:25 y:N-d16c3206c12f5644-0000000000
drwxr-xr-x  2 root  root  4096 Apr 26 17:50 Y:p-05b9ee59a8e426da-0000000000
drwxr-xr-x  2 root  root  4096 Apr 22 19:20 yp-6131660bc56433f0-0000000000
drwxr-xr-x  2 root  root  4096 Apr 26 21:20 Yz-57ca695582281830-0000000000
drwxr-xr-x  2 root  root  4096 Apr 22 12:20 Z-056bc56238327542-0000000000
drwxr-xr-x  2 root  root  4096 Apr 22 17:05 Z-06d6559ea7d8d81e-0000000000
drwxr-xr-x  2 root  root  4096 Apr 15 09:15 z-078580c414cd831a-0000000000
drwxr-xr-x  2 root  root  4096 Apr 14 15:05 z-1c234db314fd3d4f-0000000000
drwxr-xr-x  2 root  root  4096 Apr 17 16:40 Z3-fb84f61e06366829-0000000000
drwxr-xr-x  2 root  root  4096 Apr 16 10:00 _Z-475f2f63ed961d9b-0000000000
drwxr-xr-x  2 root  root  4096 Apr 22 18:45 -Z-4d85b858dd07d49a-0000000000
drwxr-xr-x  2 root  root  4096 Apr 18 17:40 z-7549c367428e3062-0000000000
```

Edit:
Is there a way to  trap and log which process is writing these files?

Comment: What's inside them?  What does `fuser /Y-df78a7ff0627a98c-0000000000` return (pick the newest directory).  Are there any processes running you don't recognise?  Is the machine connected to the Internet?

Comment: The directories are empty, there are no processes running I do not recognise. The machine is connected to the internet, it is acting as a gateway / firewall. I'm using firewalld.

Comment: I would disconnect it from the Internet while you investigate.  Can you try the `fuser` or @linerd's `lsof` command.

Comment: My guess would be a cron job using unquoted and/or incorrectly defined variable(s) to create a temporary working directory, and then not properly cleaning up after itself.  Check any local (i.e. not part of a system package) scripts called from root's `crontab`, as well as`/etc/crontab` and `/etc/cron*/*` - especially any that run every 5 minutes.

Comment: Maybe the cron job script has a simple mistake, like using `$tmp` rather than `$TMP` or `$TMPDIR`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lsof` and `grep` to find out the process open these files

`$ lsof | grep "Y.+0000000000"`

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like a `cron` job creating temporary working directories and then failing to clean up after itself properly.

To verify that, examine any local (i.e. not part of a system package) scripts called from root's `crontab`, as well as `/etc/crontab` and `/etc/cron*/*` - especially any that run every 5 minutes

---

My initial guess was that it would be a cron script using unquoted and/or incorrectly defined variable(s), but a (now deleted) response from you mentioned that it was `HandBrakeCLI`, installled from the negativo17 repo (http://negativo17.org/)

`HandBrakeCLI` does not do this on my system (version 1:0.10.5-dmo1 from the debian-multimedia repo), so it looks like a bug in your version of `handbrake`.  You should report the bug to negativo17, or check to see if they have an updated/fixed version.