# Weird Log/Cache Files/Directories in a User's Home Directory

Tags: files, macintosh, home

I use the latest version of Mac OSX Version 14.0, which is not solely related to that. This has been occurring since the previous versions. In my home directory, there has been persistent log files with weird names that seem to be undelteable. When I try to delete them, they reappear and start forming as fast as I deleted them. They are named weirdly; as far as I can tell, they are some log or cache directories and files. The only way that I figure they are some cache or log file is because of the systematic names and some of the content labeled with some sort of relation to cache. I launched a terminal from my home directory and have done a `ls -la`. The entire file can be seen [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QzHCjLF08vhDwx0CEM4AWVOdYJJ_MJcp/view?usp=sharing) with a bit more description below. I looked at [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/279694/589053) and [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/649408/589053) before coming here and writing this question but feel free to edit.

The first part of my `ls` command comes back fine:

```
dyl :) ls -la 
total 768
drwxr-xr-x@ 265 dylanmxx  staff    8480 Oct 10 13:26 .
drwxr-xr-x    5 root         admin     160 Sep 24 12:08 ..
srwxr-xr-x    1 dylanmxx  staff       0 Mar 17  2021 .Box_EngineServer
srwxr-xr-x    1 dylanmxx  staff       0 Mar 17  2021 .Box_StreemToSync
srwxr-xr-x    1 dylanmxx  staff       0 Mar 17  2021 .Box_SyncToStreem
srwxr-xr-x    1 dylanmxx  staff       0 Mar 17  2021 .Box_UIServer
-r--------    1 dylanmxx  staff       7 Sep 21  2016 .CFUserTextEncoding
drwx------    2 dylanmxx  staff      64 Dec  7  2021 .DDLocalBackups
drwx------    2 dylanmxx  staff      64 Dec  7  2021 .DDPreview
-rw-r--r--@   1 dylanmxx  staff  294916 Oct 17 21:53 .DS_Store
drwx------+  14 dylanmxx  staff     448 Sep 25 15:47 .Trash
drwxr-xr-x    2 dylanmxx  staff      64 Nov 23  2016 .WDHiddenItems
-rw-------    1 dylanmxx  staff       0 Apr  8  2020 .Xauthority
drwxr-x--x    3 dylanmxx  staff      96 Dec 19  2017 .adobe
drwxr-xr-x   12 dylanmxx  staff     384 Nov  7  2022 .android
-rw-r--r--    1 dylanmxx  staff     778 Aug 30  2022 .anyconnect
drwxr-xr-x@  12 dylanmxx  staff     384 Sep 28  2022 .arduinoIDE
```

But then after all the `.files` are done these weird logfiles with examples below show up:

```
lrwx------    1 dylanmxx  staff      20 Jan  2  2023 1-2-20231-2-20231-2-20231-2-20231-2-20231-2-20231-2-20231-2-20231-2-20231-2-20231-2-20231-2-20231-2-20231-2-20231-2-20231-2-20231-2-20231-2-20231-2-20231-2-20231-2-20231-2-20231-2-20231-2-20231-2-20231-2-20231-2-20231-2-20231-2-20231-2-2023Google Drive -> /Volumes/GoogleDrive
drwxr-xr-x@   4 dylanmxx  staff     128 Oct 10  2022 10-10-202210-10-202210-10-202210-10-202210-10-202210-10-202210-10-202210-10-202210-10-202210-10-202210-10-202210-10-202210-10-202210-10-202210-10-202210-10-202210-10-202210-10-202210-10-202210-10-202210-10-202210-10-202210-10-2022.plastic4
drwxr-xr-x@   4 dylanmxx  staff     128 Oct 10  2022 10-10-202210-10-202210-10-202210-10-202210-10-202210-10-202210-10-202210-10-202210-10-202210-10-202210-10-202210-10-202210-10-202210-10-202210-10-202210-10-202210-10-202210-10-202210-10-202210-10-202210-10-202210-10-202210-10-202210-10-2022.plastic4
drwxr-xr-x    4 dylanmxx  staff     128 Oct 10 13:25 10-10-202310-10-202310-10-202310-10-202310-10-202310-10-202310-10-202310-10-202310-10-202310-10-202310-10-202310-10-202310-10-202310-10-202310-10-202310-10-202310-10-202310-10-202310-10-202310-10-202310-10-202310-10-202310-10-202310-10-202310-10-2023.npm
drwxr-xr-x@   4 dylanmxx  staff     128 Oct 12  2022 10-12-202210-12-202210-12-202210-12-202210-12-202210-12-202210-12-202210-12-202210-12-202210-12-202210-12-202210-12-202210-12-202210-12-202210-12-202210-12-202210-12-202210-12-202210-12-202210-12-202210-12-202210-12-202210-12-2022.plastic4
drwxr-xr-x@   4 dylanmxx  staff     128 Oct 12  2022 10-12-202210-12-202210-12-202210-12-202210-12-202210-12-202210-12-202210-12-202210-12-202210-12-202210-12-202210-12-202210-12-202210-12-202210-12-202210-12-202210-12-202210-12-202210-12-202210-12-202210-12-202210-12-202210-12-202210-12-2022.plastic4
drwxr-xr-x@   4 dylanmxx  staff     128 Oct 13  2022 10-13-2022.plastic4
drwxr-xr-x@   4 dylanmxx  staff     128 Oct 13  2022 10-13-202210-13-2022.plastic4
drwxr-xr-x@   4 dylanmxx  staff     128 Oct 13  2022 10-13-202210-13-202210-13-2022.plastic4
drwxr-xr-x@   4 dylanmxx  staff     128 Oct 13  2022 10-13-202210-13-202210-13-202210-13-2022.plastic4
drwxr-xr-x@   4 dylanmxx  staff     128 Oct 13  2022 10-13-202210-13-202210-13-202210-13-202210-13-2022.plastic4
drwxr-xr-x@   4 dylanmxx  staff     128 Oct 13  2022 10-13-202210-13-202210-13-202210-13-202210-13-202210-13-2022.plastic4
drwxr-xr-x@   4 dylanmxx  staff     128 Oct 13  2022 10-13-202210-13-202210-13-202210-13-202210-13-202210-13-202210-13-2022.plastic4
```

```
drwxr-xr-x@   2 dylanmxx  staff      64 Oct 31  2022 10-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-2022.plastic4
drwxr-xr-x@   3 dylanmxx  staff      96 Oct 31  2022 10-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-2022.mono
drwxr-xr-x@   2 dylanmxx  staff      64 Oct 31  2022 10-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-2022.plastic4
drwxr-xr-x@   7 dylanmxx  staff     224 Oct 31  2022 10-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-2022.IdentityService
drwxr-xr-x@   3 dylanmxx  staff      96 Oct 31  2022 10-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-2022.mono
drwxr-xr-x@   2 dylanmxx  staff      64 Oct 31  2022 10-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-2022.plastic4
drwxr-xr-x@   8 dylanmxx  staff     256 Oct 31  2022 10-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-2022.IdentityService
drwxr-xr-x@   3 dylanmxx  staff      96 Oct 31  2022 10-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-2022.mono
drwxr-xr-x@   4 dylanmxx  staff     128 Oct 31  2022 10-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-2022.plastic4
drwxr-xr-x@   3 dylanmxx  staff      96 Oct 31  2022 10-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-2022.mono
drwxr-xr-x@   4 dylanmxx  staff     128 Oct 31  2022 10-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-2022.plastic4
drwxr-xr-x@   3 dylanmxx  staff      96 Oct 31  2022 10-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-202210-31-2022.templateengine
```

Does anyone know how I could be more clear about what the issue is I then have regular files towards the end of the `ls` command.

```
drwxr-xr-x    4 dylanmxx  staff     128 Nov 23  2016 Applications
-rw-r--r--@   1 dylanmxx  staff      83 Jan  8  2022 Brewfile
drwx------@   4 dylanmxx  staff     128 May 26 17:29 Creative Cloud Files
drwx------@  18 dylanmxx  staff     576 Aug 12 15:01 Desktop
drwx------@  35 dylanmxx  staff    1120 Oct 10 12:07 Documents
drwx------@   7 dylanmxx  staff     224 Sep 25 16:50 Downloads
drwx------@ 130 dylanmxx  staff    4160 Sep 19 13:39 Library
drwx------+   9 dylanmxx  staff     288 Mar 28  2021 Movies
```

Comment: It just looks like something moved some files to `10-31-2022<filename>` repeatedly. These are a year old now, best you can do is maybe inspect the files with `file` or `less`.

Comment: `drwxr-xr-x@` the initial `d` indicates that those listings are dirrectories. `cd` into one and see what is there. (not sure what the `@` is on the end. `man ls` may tell you. Good luck.

Comment: Wow, those are really "wide" direcdtory names. Did you notice the one ending with `.....-20231-2-20231-2-20231-2-20231-2-2023Google Drive -> /Volumes/GoogleDrive` ? That seem suspicious. I recommend highlighting that in your question. Good luck.

Comment: One of the directories was created on Oct 10th this year.  Looks like a badly configured backup or rotate issue.  I would check any scheduled jobs to see if they could be the culprit. Your home directory should not be used to house these

Comment: There should not be any scheduled jobs because this is my personal computer and rarely do any developing on it. Where would I find them? Any suggestions? @rr0ss0rr

Comment: @mendesd Since you have homebrew installed, I would start there with `brew services list` to list services that were installed using `brew`.  all the places scheduled jobs can be located are: ~/Library/LaunchAgents
/Library/LaunchAgents
/Library/LaunchDaemons
/System/Library/LaunchAgents
/System/Library/LaunchDaemons

Comment: Are you using PlasticSCM? 
Looks like it's might be fighting with Google Drive on keeping backups